# Does the insignificance of a regressor imply insignificance of differenced predicted probabilities with respect to this regressor in probit model?

Tags: statistical-significance, predictive-models, probit

Suppose I fit a probit model (with two regressors) to data and obtain predicted probabilities: $\widehat{Pr}(Y=1|x_1,x_2)=\Phi(\beta_0+\widehat{\beta}_1x_1+\widehat{\beta}_2x_2)$. For simplicity, suppose $x_2\in\{0,1\}$, and suppose that $\widehat{\beta}_2$ is insignificant at 5% significance level. Does this imply that for $x_1=\overline{x}_1$,  $\widehat{Pr}(Y=1|\overline{x}_1,1)-\widehat{Pr}(Y=1|\overline{x}_1,0)$ is also insignificant? My guess is that it doesn't imply, as it depends on the sampling distribution of $\widehat{Pr}(Y=1|\overline{x}_1,1)-\widehat{Pr}(Y=1|\overline{x}_1,0)$, and it's entirely possible that it is significantly different from zero at 5% significance level. Am I correct?